# How can I remove destination path that already exists in git?

Tags: git, debugging, github, bitbucket

I'm having this strange behavior where I have 2 repositories (that I've made in bitbucket) in my project directory.  I get an error that says `fatal: destination path 'gitsub' already exists and is not an empty directory.`.

I want to delete these repos indefinitely so I can start fresh again.  How can I do that?

I tried running these commands but they all failed (gitsub and gittest are repo names) :

```
git rm -f --cached gitsub
git rm -f --cached gittest
rm -r .git
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: Do `ls -al` and see what's in this directory.

Comment: @matt ran that command and saw a whole bunch of stuff.  In particular, I do see gitsub and gittest!

Comment: So those are your repos? Do you want to delete them completely, losing your test code, or do you want to delete just the fact that they are under `.git` control. If the former, just throw them away (drag to the trash).

Comment: @matt omg that was it, thank you!  I should've been more vigilant.

Comment: OK I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the command line. Just throw the `gittest` and `gitsub` folders in the trash. Their `.git` repos are inside and will be thrown away with them. Note that you lost all your work — you are throwing away the working directory — but it sounds like that's what you want to do, and if you have already pushed to bitbucket you can always clone a new working directory and get your work back.